# Cannot find test-persistence.xml using ShrinkWrap

Tags: java, maven, persistence, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I'm building an integration test with ShrinkWrap and I wish to test the persistence using a test file `test-persistence.xml`. According to the Arquillian Guides [Testing Java Persistence](http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/), I need to [write the test](http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/#write_the_test) like this:

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
        .addPackage(Game.class.getPackage())
        .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
        .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
}
```

And here's my own implementation :

```
@Deployment
public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
    WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
        .addPackages(true, "org.hibernate.search.jsr352")
        .addPackages(true, "javax.persistence")
        .addPackages(true, "org.hibernate.search.annotations")
        .addClass(Serializable.class)
        .addClass(Date.class)
        .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
//      .addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml")
        .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
        .addAsResource("META-INF/batch-jobs/mass-index.xml");
    return war;
}
```

You can see that I've commented the line `.addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml")`, which aims to search the `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` and add to the archive file. And it works fine. **However, when I replaced it by the `test-persistence.xml`, then the maven build failed with error:**

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.715 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.hibernate.search.jsr352.DeploymentIT
org.hibernate.search.jsr352.DeploymentIT  Time elapsed: 6.714 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke deployment method: public static org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive org.hibernate.search.jsr352.DeploymentIT.createDeployment()
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:43)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.container.ContainerBase.fileFromResource(ContainerBase.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.container.ContainerBase.addAsResource(ContainerBase.java:1056)
    at org.hibernate.search.jsr352.DeploymentIT.createDeployment(DeploymentIT.java:67)
```

Notice that :

- The test persistence file is located at `src/test/resources/test-persistence.xml`
- The test resources `src/test/resources` folder should be already included in maven pom file (See annex).

Any idea about how to resolve this error ?

---

### Annex

**pom.xml**

```
<testResources>
  <testResource>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/arquillian.xml</include>
      <include>**/arquillian.launch</include>
    </includes>
  </testResource>
</testResources>
```

Comment: Well, when I add `<include>test-persistence.xml</include>`, it works ... but why I need to include this, shouldn't maven include all files in the folder `src/test/resources` automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven document [Including and excluding files and directories](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) describes the usage very clearly :

> When specifying a resource directory, every file within that directory may not be used. **Thus, we may have to specify only the files that we want to include** or specify the files that we want to exclude.

To include a resource, we only need to add an `<includes>` element.

```
<project>
  ...
  <name>My Resources Plugin Practice Project</name>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>[your directory]</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>[resource file #1]</include>
          <include>[resource file #2]</include>
          <include>[resource file #3]</include>
          ...
          <include>[resource file #n]</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```